# Recursive CTE | Finding super parent id for all id's in redshift table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table org which has "id", "parent_id"
I need to find the super parent id for the "id" column  in a redshift table .

input table :

| id | parent_id |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | null |
| b1 | c1 |
| c1 | a1 |
| d1 | null |

output table :

| id | parent_id | super_parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | null | null |
| b1 | c1 | a1 |
| c1 | a1 | a1 |
| d1 | null | null |

i have tried

```
with RECURSIVE ParentHierarchy(id, parent_id, super_parent_id) AS (
  SELECT id, parent_id, id AS super_parent_id
  FROM org
  WHERE parent_id IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT t.id as id , t.parent_id as parent_id, ph.super_parent_id as super_parent_id
  FROM org t
  JOIN ParentHierarchy ph ON t.parent_id = ph.id
)
SELECT ph.id, ph.parent_id, ph.super_parent_id AS super_parent_id
FROM ParentHierarchy ph
```

I could not get the expected result. Can you please correct me.?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is nearly correct; the only adjustment needed is to select the *super_parent_id* only when the parent is not null :

```
WITH RECURSIVE ParentHierarchy(id, parent_id, super_parent_id) AS (
  SELECT id, parent_id, id AS super_parent_id
  FROM org
  WHERE parent_id IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.id as id , t.parent_id as parent_id, ph.super_parent_id as super_parent_id
  FROM org t
  JOIN ParentHierarchy ph ON t.parent_id = ph.id
)
SELECT id, parent_id, CASE WHEN parent_id IS NOT NULL THEN super_parent_id ELSE NULL END AS super_parent_id
FROM ParentHierarchy ph
ORDER BY id;
```

I suggest using a self-join query rather than a recursive query :

```
SELECT O1.id, o1.parent_id, COALESCE(o2.parent_id, o2.id) AS super_parent_id
FROM org o1
LEFT JOIN org o2 ON o1.parent_id = o2.id
```